# Django rest framework authentication database error

Tags: django, rest, api, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am trying to implement the django rest framework in my current project. The api engine is working with no security. I am trying to follow the steps given in the authentication page of django rest framework to add the authentication.

When I am adding the following section to the settings.py, I don't get any error:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
]
}
```

but when I am adding 'rest_framework.authtoken' to the INSTALLED_APPS, and run the server,

I get the follwing message:

> You have 2 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): authtoken.
>   Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

Then I tried running:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and I get the following errors:

> (raiotic-venv) username@username-VirtualBox:~/Servers/Repositories/raiotic-venv/raiotic$ python manage.py migrate
>   Operations to perform:
>     Apply all migrations: MainApp, admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions
>   Running migrations:
>     Applying authtoken.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql)
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 381, in execute
>       return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "manage.py", line 21, in 
>       main()
>     File "manage.py", line 17, in main
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 375, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
>       res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
>       fake_initial=fake_initial,
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
>       state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
>       state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
>       state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
>       operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 92, in database_forwards
>       schema_editor.create_model(model)
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 307, in create_model
>       self.execute(sql, params or None)
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 137, in execute
>       cursor.execute(sql, params)
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
>       return super().execute(sql, params)
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
>       return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
>     File "/home/username/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
>       return executor(sql, params, many, context)
>    File "/home/username/venvlib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>     File "/home/username/venvlib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in **exit**
>       raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
>     File "/home/username/venvlib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql)
>     File "/home/username/venvlib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 381, in execute
>       return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
>   django.db.utils.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database

Answer (score 0):

try changing the permissions to the db.sqlite3 file it might be that the mode is read only for the user you are running as having no permissions to write to the file.

do

```
ls -al db.sqlite3
chmod a+w db.sqlite3
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Thanks TralahM. It was a permission issue. However, changing the permission using chmod did not fix it. I could see that the permission has changed but django was not responsive. So I deleted the sqlite file, then change the django db path to a different folder. Performed the migration. Then changed it back to the original location and migrated again. It seems to be working right now.